# Targeting a specific class inside an id using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following id of a table element:

```
<tr id="_IWID_Filters_included">
    <td width="20%" class="lotusFormLabel lotusFormFieldRow lotusNowrap"> </td>
    <td class="lotusFormFieldRow"> </td>
</tr>
```

I want to append a string into the td class "lotusFormFieldRow". Currently, I only know how to append a string targeting $("#_IWID_Filters_included").append("string"); which only appends the string to the end of *IWID* before /tr. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Currently, I have :

```
    $("#_IWID_Filters_included").append(
        "<td class = 'lotusFormFieldRow'>" + 
        "<div id='filter_" + current_index + "'>" +
        "Filter name: <select id = 'dimensionName_" + current_index + "' class='lotusText'></select>" + 
        "Filter value: <select id ='dimensionId_" + current_index + "' class='lotusText'></select>" +
        "<button type='button' id='remove_btn_" + current_index + "' onclick='filter_forms.remove_filter_form(" + current_index + ")' style='margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;'>Remove filter</button>" +
        "</div>" + 
        "</td>" + "<td width='7%' class='lotusFormFieldRow'>" + "</td>" 
    );
```

However, instead of having the td class be part of the string, it needs to be inside IWID_Filters_included so that I can just put the last td width at the end. The main issue right now is that every time I click "Add filter", the td width is appended which is disrupting the spacing of the table; hence, why I need a way to target td class = lotusFormFieldRow specifically.

Comment: I'll make an update with more context regarding my problem, including that.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
$('#_IWID_Filters_included .lotusFormFieldRow').append('I am appending this string now!');
```

Helpful Tip: If you wanted to append something BEFORE the other content in that specified element use `.prepend` instead of `.append`

Answer (score 1):

Append adds after the selector - `.text()` or `.html()` will insert into the selector, depending if you need a string or markup.

```
$(".lotusFormFieldRow").text("string");
```

Comment: .html() also works for my case! Thanks, but my question was how to select the selector.

Answer (score 1):

YO you can append string using: var string = "something" + "something else". GG